# Почему не работает UPDATE запрос в SQLite?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть такая БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я при нажатии на кнопку хочу вписать в БД trading style текст с кнопки
Я делаю так

```
def add_ts(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET ('trading_style')='Среднесрочная' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,))
```

А вписать пытаюсь так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="cratcosrochnaya")
async def cratcosrochnaya(message: types.Message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Текст для Краткосрочная")
    return db.add_ts(message.from_user.id)
```

Проблема в том что без WHERE и всего что после него запрос работает, но меняет все ячейки сразу.

```
"UPDATE 'users' SET ('trading_style')='Среднесрочная'" - работает
"UPDATE 'users' SET ('trading_style')='Среднесрочная' WHERE 'user_id' = ?" - НЕ работает
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А нафиг здесь `('trading_style')` скобки? Как Вы подключаетесь к БД? Что, в данном случае, такое `self` (Объект какого класса оно представляет)?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в неправильном формировании запроса (нужно было убрать '')